# How to use truncating on elements and read more button with angular?

Tags: html, angularjs, truncate

I am trying to use angular truncate to truncate some elements. I know how to truncate words by `{{something.something | characters:50}}`. But what i want to do is, for example, i have a bold text `<b> Comfortable </b>` and then i have 3 other features listed `<span> Air conditioned </span> 
<span> Safe </span>

<span> Fast </span>`

I want to add a read me button.
Now what i want basically is only the "Comfortable" will be visible at first but when someone click the read more button it will be expanded and show the rest 3  . How can i do that? I dont want to use jQuery here. Can this be done in angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy to achieve. You should initialize the readmore in your controller also.

```
<div>
   <span >Comfortable</span>
   <span ng-show="readmore"> Air conditioned </span> 
   <span ng-show="readmore"> Safe </span>
   <span ng-show="readmore"> Fast </span>
   <div ng-hide="readmore" ng-click="readmore = true">Read more</div>
   <div ng-show="readmore" ng-click="readmore = false">Read less</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you have a list of dynamic items where you use ng-repeat you would use filter to decide how many you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

If possible put this tag to cover all your span (except Bold one)

```
<a ng-click="isShowMore = !isShowMore" ng-hide="isShowMore">Show More</a>
 <div ng-show="isShowMore">
    <span> Air conditioned </span>
 </div>
<a ng-click="isShowMore = !isShowMore" ng-show="isShowMore">Show Less</a>
```

Comment: You might change the design with your solution by adding everything inside a div

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use ng-hide , ng-show or ng-if.

```
<b> Comfortable </b>
<button ng-click="visible = true">Read More...</button>
<div ng-show="visible">
   <span>...</span> 
   <span>...</span>
   <span>...</span>
</div>
```